# How to stop titles in Android tabs from wrapping in the middle of a word?

Tags: android, text, tabs, title, word-wrap

I have a layout with several tabs. What's happening is that in landscape orientation, the layout is wrapping the text used in the tab titles, but not on a word - its wrapping in the middle of a word! So a title like:

```
Description
```

looks fine in portrait but in landscape is shown like this:

```
Desc  
ript  
ion
```

I'm not specifying any word wrap or style attributes for the text. I would imagine the layout would have more space in landscape mode than portrait, so this makes no sense. Would appreciate any advice on what to look at.

Answer (score 20):

Late response, but Google brought me here, so this might be useful still.

You can choose to scroll the tabs, which I believe is preferable to changing font sizes.

**app:tabMode="scrollable"**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

- Do you use the same layout file for landscape and portrait?
- Are the width of your tabs set to `wrap_content`?
- Try setting `singleLine="true"` on the tab text
- Does the width of the tab graphic increase when changed to landscape?
- Are you using a custom background on the tabs and if so is it a nine-patch?

Although TBH I usually use a RadioGroup and a FrameLayout to achieve tabs because it provides more control (you can't change the tab strip drawable prior to 2.2, and using this method your tabs can be separated from the tab content so you can put either wherever you want).

Comment: 1. No, the landscape layout is slightly different so its a separate file. However, the tabhost is the same and in both cases the tabs are added programmatically (using TabSpec, etc) - same code runs for either portrait or landscape mode.

Comment: 2. Yes, the tabs are set to wrap_content.

Comment: 3. Tested this. Yes it stops the wrapping, but I actually *do* want wordwrap because some tab titles are > 1 word. The word wrapping works fine in portrait orientation.

Comment: 4. Hard to say (the layout is slightly different though the window is wider in landscape) - would hierarchy viewer help me to check the widths?

Comment: 5. Yes we are using a selector with 9-patch images for the states.

Comment: Okay then: 1) Try changing/removing the content margins from your 9-patch (to see if your image is at fault) 2) Remove the landscape layout and give it a test with the portrait layout in landscape -- if the buttons resize properly this time it's your layout file 3) Yep you can use Hierarchy Viewer and Pixel Perfect

Comment: 1. Removing some padding from tabs seemed to help a little.

Comment: 2. Unfortunately, landscape *is* different so we need to keep it around.

Answer (score 0):

OK, we managed to fix this. Had to reduce font size by 1pt size and reduce left+right padding on tabs. We also noticed that in landscape the tabs were all the same size but in portrait they weren't, so obviously somewhere we had a fill_parent instead of a wrap_content. Fix seems to work for both 7" and 10" tablets. Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Manage this, with

Override this class in project ActionBarSherlock ./ActionbarSherlock/src/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/widget/ScrollingTabContainerView.java

```
@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    if (mParent.mMaxTabWidth > 0 && getMeasuredWidth() > mParent.mMaxTabWidth) {

        //comment this line

       // super.onMeasure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mParent.mMaxTabWidth, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),heightMeasureSpec);

       //now do nothing , override by me for ActionBarTabs not rezize never
      //this method manage the size tabs, if you want you can count caracters to resize the size width
    }
}
```